# Solving codingBat 'evenOdd' with one loop in Java

Tags: java

The question is about Solving [this](http://codingbat.com/prob/p105771) problem from codingBat in Java.

**Problem Statement:**

*Return an array that contains the exact same numbers as the given array, but rearranged so that all the even numbers come before all the odd numbers. Other than that, the numbers can be in any order. You may modify and return the given array, or make a new array.*

> evenOdd({1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}) → {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}
>
> evenOdd({3, 3, 2}) → {2, 3, 3}
>
> evenOdd({2, 2, 2}) → {2, 2, 2}

The Problem is simple with 2 loops I attempted at solving it with 1 it got too lengthy I believe, is there any other efficient way to solve the above problem using 1 loop?
do not use collections!

**My solution:**

```
public int[] evenOdd(int[] nums) {

boolean oddFound=false;
int count=-1;
int oddGap=0;

for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
  {
     if(!(oddFound)&(nums[i]%2==0))
       continue;

       if((!oddFound)&(nums[i]%2==1))
       {
         oddFound=true;
         count=i;
         continue;
       }
       if((oddFound)&(nums[i]%2==1))
       {
         oddGap++;
         continue;
       }
        if((oddFound)&(nums[i]%2==0)) 
        {
         int temp=nums[count];
         nums[count]=nums[i];  
         nums[i]=temp;

         if(i>0)
             i--;

            if(oddGap>0)
            {
              oddGap--;
              count+=1;
              oddFound=true;
              continue;
             } 
             oddFound=false;
        } 

     }
     return nums;    

}
```

Comment: Why the restriction on not creating a new array or using anything from collections? It's the easiest way to solve the problem

Comment: The exercise is meant for straining brain over logic anbody can solve the problem with collections.

Comment: Re-inventing the wheel isn't difficult, just incredibly tedious. Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing working code. It belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay! I finally jumped across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169300/codinbat-java-array2-evenodd?rq=1) which is actually closed but the solution by asker was almost there apart from failing in 2 cases which I fixed:

I commented out he code by asker which was making it fail in a couple of cases as seen in the question.

I think below is the simplest and most optimized solution:

```
public int[] evenOdd(int[] nums) {
int y=nums.length,x,a=0;
int temp=0;

for(x=0;x<y;x++)
{
    if(nums[x]%2==0) {
    if(a>(y-2))
       return nums;
    else{
    //nums[a]=nums[a]+nums[x];
    //nums[x]=nums[a]-nums[x];
    //nums[a]=nums[a]-nums[x];

    temp=nums[a];
    nums[a]=nums[x];
    nums[x]=temp;
    a+=1; 
        }

    } 

    return nums; 

    }
```

Comment: Lol never knew it would eventually be this simple.

Answer (score 3):

Since creating a new array is allowed, and the order of the numbers is irrelevant, I would use the following approach:

```
public int[] evenOdd(int[] nums) {
    int[] output = new int[nums.length];
    int evenPos = 0;
    int oddPos = nums.length-1;
    for (int i : nums) {
        if (i%2==0) {
            output[evenPos++]=i;
        } else {
            output[oddPos--]=i;
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Update: A somewhat less readable version that doesn't require an extra array (along the lines of what @Seelenvirtuose suggests, just without the extra loops)

```
public int[] evenOdd(int[] nums) {
    int evenPos = 0;
    int oddPos = nums.length-1;
    while (true) {
        if (evenPos>=oddPos || evenPos>=nums.length || oddPos<0) {
            break;
        }

        if (nums[evenPos]%2==0) {
            evenPos++;
        }
        if (nums[oddPos]%2!=0) {
            oddPos--;
        }

        if (evenPos<oddPos && nums[evenPos]%2 != 0 && nums[oddPos]%2 == 0) {
            int tmp = nums[evenPos];
            nums[evenPos] = nums[oddPos];
            nums[oddPos] = tmp;

            oddPos--;
            evenPos++;

        }
    }
    return nums;
}
```

Comment: A smart solution but what if making a new array is disallowed?

Comment: About perfect now! Thank you Sir!

Comment: might not work if there are only 2 items in the array. it will swap evn if they are in the correct order

Comment: @Bharath No! the edited version works in all the cases.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need any temporary lists or array because you can reorder the elements *in-situ*.

This is a simple algorithm:

1. Define two *pointers*, left and right (initially set to the bounds of the array).
2. As long as left does not *exceed* right and `nums[left]` is even, increment left.
3. As long as right does not *exceed* left and `nums[right]` is odd, decrement right.
4. If left is still less than right, swap the elements at positions left and right.
5. Repeat 2,3,4 as long as left is still less than right.

Got it? Here some code:

```
public int[] evenOdd(int[] nums) {
    // (1)
    int left = 0;
    int right = nums.length -1;
    do {
        // (2)
        while (left < right && nums[left] % 2 == 0)
            left += 1;
        // (3)
        while (right > left && nums[right] % 2 != 0)
            right -= 1;
        // (4)
        if (left < right) {
            int temp = nums[left];
            nums[left] = nums[right];
            nums[right] = temp;
        }
    } while (left < right);   // (5)
    return nums;
}
```

Comment: Neatly explained algo...but it does make of more than one loop, what would be the Big-O complexity of this?

Comment: This is O(n)! Look at the increment and decrement strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Traverse evenOdd from 0 to N.
for every even number encountered, copy it to the required position on the evenOdd array. 
for every odd num encountered, store it in a separate array called oddnum.
After traversing the whole array, just copy the elements from oddnum to the Back of evenOdd.

Ex: evenOdd = {5,2,1,4}
Step 1. copy 5 to oddnum[0]
2. copy 2 to evenodd[0]
3. copy 1 to oddnum[1]
4. copy 1 to evenodd[1]
5. cpy oddnum[0] to evenOdd[2] and oddnum[1] to evenOdd[3]

Comment: but that would require more than one loop

Comment: Does the question state that u shouldn't use 2 loops or does it say u shudn't use 2 nested loops ?

Comment: No nested loops not more than 1 outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping to your restrictions, here's a one-loop answer:

```
public int[] evenOdd(int[] nums) {
    int[] result = new int[nums.length];
    int nextEven = 0;
    int nextOdd = nums.length - 1;

    for ( int num : nums )
    {
        if ( num % 2 == 0 )
            result[ nextEven++ ] = num;
        else
            result[ nextOdd-- ] = num;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: That is so similar to solution @mth :)

Comment: There's only so many ways to boil an egg; I'm not sure if his edit or my answer came first.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public int[] evenOdd(int[] nums) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {

        if (nums[i] % 2 == 0) {

            int temp = nums[i];

            nums[i] = nums[count];
            nums[count] = temp;

            count++;

        }

    }

    return nums;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[] evenOdd(int[] nums) {
  Stack stack = new Stack();
  int[] nums2 = new int[nums.length];
  for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if(nums[i] % 2 != 0) {
      stack.push(nums[i]);
    }
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if(nums[i] % 2 == 0) {
      stack.push(nums[i]);
    }
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    nums2[i] = (Integer) stack.pop();
  }
  return nums2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In-place version (stable):

We continually search for te first and last invalid values (first odd, before last even) and keep swapping them until they cross:

```
public int[] evenOdd(int[] nums) {
  int first = 0, last = nums.length - 1;
  while (first < last) {
    while ((first < last) &&  isOdd(nums[last]))  last--;
    while ((first < last) && !isOdd(nums[first])) first++;
    swap(nums, first, last);
  }
  return nums;
}

boolean isOdd(int num) { return (num & 1) == 1; }
void swap(int[] nums, int i, int j) {
  int copy = nums[i];
  nums[i] = nums[j];
  nums[j] = copy;
}
```

---

With auxiliaries (stable):

We partition the even and odd values in separate lists and concatenate them back:

```
public int[] evenOdd(int[] nums) {
  List<Integer> evens = new ArrayList<Integer>(nums.length);
  List<Integer> odds = new ArrayList<Integer>(nums.length);
  for (int num : nums)
    if (isOdd(num)) odds.add(num);
    else evens.add(num);

  int[] results = new int[nums.length];
  int i = 0;
  for (int num : evens) results[i++] = num;
  for (int num : odds) results[i++] = num;
  return results;
}

boolean isOdd(int num) { return (num & 1) == 1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplified solution which uses ***Srteam API***:

```
public int[] evenOdd(int[] nums) {
  int[] evenOddArr = new int[nums.length];;
  int[] evenArr = Arrays.stream(nums).filter(x -> x % 2 == 0).toArray();;
  int[] oddArr = Arrays.stream(nums).filter(x -> x % 2 != 0).toArray();
  
  evenOddArr = java.util.stream.IntStream.concat(Arrays.stream(evenArr), Arrays.stream(oddArr))
                    .toArray();
  
  return evenOddArr;
}
```

It passes all the tests on CodingBat:
[image: Test results for evenOdd task]